# discord.py: level system - cogs

Tags: discord.py

Whenever I tried running the code below it but it just doesn't seem to work. I am really new to all of this.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import json
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='')

class lvls(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.Cog.listener
    async def on_member_join(self, member):
        with open(r"C:\Users\Frank\Desktop\BOTZS\test.py", 'r') as f:
            users = json.load(f)

        await update_data(users, member)

        with open('LvlUP.json', 'w') as f:
            json.dump(users, f)

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_message(self, message):
        if message.author.bot == False:
            with open('LvlUP.json', 'r') as f:
                users = json.load(f)

            await update_data(users, message.author)
            await add_experience(users, message.author, 5)
            await level_up(users, message.author, message)

            with open('LvlUP.json', 'w') as f:
                json.dump(users, f)

    async def update_data(self, users, user):
        if not f'{user.id}' in users:
            users[f'{user.id}'] = {}
            users[f'{user.id}']['experience'] = 0
            users[f'{user.id}']['level'] = 1

    async def add_experience(self, users, user, exp):
        users[f'{user.id}']['experience'] += exp

    async def level_up(self, users, user, message):
        experience = users[f'{user.id}']['experience']
        lvl_start = users[f'{user.id}']['level']
        lvl_end = int(experience ** (1 / 4))
        if lvl_start < lvl_end:
            embed = discord.Embed(title="**LEVEL UP!**",
                                  description=f'{user.mention} has leveled up to level {lvl_end}! :fire: 'f'\n Soundwave Superior,{user.mention} Inferior ',
                                  color=discord.Color.dark_red())
            embed.set_thumbnail(url=user.avatar_url)
            users[f'{user.id}']['level'] = lvl_end
            await message.channel.send(embed=embed)


def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(lvls(client))
```

[image]

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: sorry! I will be more careful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `()` for `commands.Cog.listener`:

```py
# Your code
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_member_join(self, member):
# Your code
```

You need to setup client in the end of the file:

```py
# Your code 
setup(client)
```

And you need to run client after setup:

```py
# Your code 
setup(client)
client.run('YOUR_TOKEN') # Set your token for the bot
```

**Full code** if you don't understand my comments:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import json
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='')

class lvls(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_member_join(self, member):
        with open(r"C:\Users\Frank\Desktop\BOTZS\test.py", 'r') as f:
            users = json.load(f)

        await update_data(users, member)

        with open('LvlUP.json', 'w') as f:
            json.dump(users, f)

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_message(self, message):
        if message.author.bot == False:
            with open('LvlUP.json', 'r') as f:
                users = json.load(f)

            await update_data(users, message.author)
            await add_experience(users, message.author, 5)
            await level_up(users, message.author, message)

            with open('LvlUP.json', 'w') as f:
                json.dump(users, f)

    async def update_data(self, users, user):
        if not f'{user.id}' in users:
            users[f'{user.id}'] = {}
            users[f'{user.id}']['experience'] = 0
            users[f'{user.id}']['level'] = 1

    async def add_experience(self, users, user, exp):
        users[f'{user.id}']['experience'] += exp

    async def level_up(self, users, user, message):
        experience = users[f'{user.id}']['experience']
        lvl_start = users[f'{user.id}']['level']
        lvl_end = int(experience ** (1 / 4))
        if lvl_start < lvl_end:
            embed = discord.Embed(title="**LEVEL UP!**",
                                  description=f'{user.mention} has leveled up to level {lvl_end}! :fire: 'f'\n Soundwave Superior,{user.mention} Inferior ',
                                  color=discord.Color.dark_red())
            embed.set_thumbnail(url=user.avatar_url)
            users[f'{user.id}']['level'] = lvl_end
            await message.channel.send(embed=embed)


def setup(client):
    client.add_cog(lvls(client))

setup(client)
client.run('YOUR_TOKEN')
```

I hope it's help you.

UPD: Try to add `self.` for your functions:

```py
# on_member_join
await self.update_data(users, member)

# on_message
await self.update_data(users, message.author)
await self.add_experience(users, message.author, 5)
await self.level_up(users, message.author, message)
```